Permission danied when reading file from /var/lib/mysql-files
I am using cursor.execute to generate the file my_file.csv and save it in /var/lib/mysql-files.
Here is my code:
import mysql.connector

connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', port='3306', database='my_db', user='my_user', password='my_pass')
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('''select my_db.my_table.my_column '''
           '''from my_db.my_table '''
           '''into outfile '/var/lib/mysql-files/my_file.csv' '''
           '''fields optionally enclosed by '"' terminated by ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ''')

cursor.close()
connection.close()

Then I try to read this file with pandas directly from the /var/lib/mysql-files directory.
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv("/var/lib/mysql-files/my_file.csv")

And I got this error:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/mysql-files/my_file.csv'

My Question: how do I get permission to read the file my_file.csv from the /var/lib/mysql-files directory?
Note 1: I tried to change the permission on /var/lib/mysql-files directory with this command:
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql-files

but I still get the same permission error.
Note 2: I tried to include my user in the mysql group by running this command in the terminal on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS:
sudo usermod -a -G mysql $(whoami)

but I still get the same permission error.

A ls -l on the concerned directory shows that it is owned by mysql user and group.
In order to get read access granted, you must be part of the mysql group (or use the mysql user).
To add your current user to the mysql group you can execute: usermod -aG mysql $(whoami). Then logout and login.
Or, as a quick test, run newgrp mysql and restart your script from the same console to confirm your issue is solved.
EDIT:
You are getting confused with the system shell and the mysql interactive shell. All of the above commands are to be executed from the system shell (sh, bash, zsh, ...):
$ usermod -aG mysql $(whoami)
$ newgrp mysql
$ python3 ... # your python script


Thanks for your reply, but I'm not sure I understand how I can add my current user to the mysql group.
I logged in like this: mysql -u my_user -p.
After entering the password, I ran the command: usrmod -aG mysql $(whoami).
I got this error:  ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'usrmod -aG mysql $(whoami)' at line 1 

Thanks again.
I ran these two commands in the system shell: sudo usermod -aG mysql $(whoami), newgrp mysql. Then I ran my python script, like this: python3 /home/my_user/Desktop/my_script.py. But I still getting the error:  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/mysql-files/my_file.csv' 

Note: I use sudo usermod -aG mysql $(whoami) instead of usermod -aG mysql $(whoami) because with the second command I got this error message: usermod: Permission denied. usermod: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.

@B612 try using your user name instead of $(wohami) as you run it with sudo?

Thanks. That solved the problem. But I still have a doubt: if I want to run my python script through the PyCharm IDE, I still get the permission error. I tried running the commands: sudo usermod -aG mysql $(whoami) and newgrp mysql in the PyCharm integrated terminal, but I still get the permission error. Do you know what might be happening?

Once you added your current user to the mysql group (with usermod) you have to logout first and then login again for the changes to take effect. From there, you should be able to access the files owned by mysql user wether it is from the console, the file browser, or your ide

Sorry. I did logout first and then login again (after running sudo usermod -aG mysql $(whoami) and newgrp mysqlon system shell) . Then I run my python code on PyCharm ide. But I still getting this permission error on PyCharm integrated terminal: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/mysql-files/my_file.csv'. Do you know what I could be doing wrong?

Nope, may be this new issue is related to your ide (which I don't know) and you should ask for an other question with other details?

Yes, I will post a new question. Thank you.
